# HTML Tag parse error in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, html

I use this code:

```
alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text));
```

And the string text contains:

```
<strong>Hello StackOverflow!</strong>, <em>today it's a beatiful day!</em>.
```

It works like a charm in Android 4.0.3! However, in Android 2.3.3, the tags are inverted! The `<strong>` tag makes the text italic, and the `<em>` tag makes the text bold!!

I have no idea why. The LogCat doesn't report anything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This <strike>seems to be</strike> [is](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3473) a bug. Have a look at the sources of the `HTML`-class for [Android 2.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java#HtmlToSpannedConverter.handleStartTag%28java.lang.String,org.xml.sax.Attributes%29) (not yours, but close):

```
private void handleStartTag(String tag, Attributes attributes) {
    //... Other if's
    } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
        start(mSpannableStringBuilder, new Bold());
    } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("strong")) {
        start(mSpannableStringBuilder, new Italic()); // <-- PROBLEM
    }
    // ... More here
}
```

This has been fixed in the [Android 4.2.2 sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/text/Html.java#HtmlToSpannedConverter.handleStartTag%28java.lang.String,org.xml.sax.Attributes%29):

```
private void handleStartTag(String tag, Attributes attributes) {
    // Others up here...
    else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("strong")) {
        start(mSpannableStringBuilder, new Bold()); // <- FIXED
    } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
        start(mSpannableStringBuilder, new Bold());
    }
    // More down here...
}
```

**Solution**: As you can see, the `<b>`-tag works as it should. You can use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3473.

From that page, it seems that the solution is to use `<b>` and `<i>` rather than `<strong>` and `<em>` because the former are defined to be bold and italic whilst the second pair are implementation dependent.

Comment: Still though gave additional option :)